# Use of unassigned local variable - if statements

Tags: c#, unassigned-variable

I'm doing the following block of code and the compiler is complaining about unassigned local variables and could use some help identifying what's up.

```
while (rsData.Read())
{
    if (rsData["TYPE"] != DBNull.Value)
        strType = rsData["TYPE"].ToString().Trim();


    if (strType == "01")
    {
        if (rsData["Text"] != DBNull.Value)
            strwho = rsData["Text"].ToString();

        if ((strwho.Length < 10 || (strwho.IndexOf("NULL") > 1)))
            strwho = "";
    }
    else if (strType == "07")
    {
        if (rsData["Text"] != DBNull.Value)
            strmetades = rsData["Text"].ToString();

        if ((strmetades.Length < 10 || (strmetades.IndexOf("NULL") > 1)))
            strmetades = "";
    }
```

It complains on all of the 'if (strType == "01")' lines and I'm not sure what's up. I've thought of using a switch for this but that seems to get the same issue also.

Any ideas?

Comment: where do you declare strType?

Comment: Are you 100% you are getting an error and not a warning?  I honestly would simply get rid of the variable and simply check the value of `rsData["TYPE"].ToString().Trim()` considering the performance costs of the doing so are trivial.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

when declaring string strType you must assign a value, something like

```
string strType = null;
```

More details: [Compiler Error CS0165](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Do I have to implicitly define them as null?

I've declared the strings at the beginning of the code but not specifically stated them as null.

Comment: yes, you need to explicitly assign any value at the moment of the declaration or before the variable is used in a sentence (in your case a if statement) you can assign either null, string.Empty, "", etc

Comment: This answer is seems misleading - there is no need to always assign a variable, providing that in the code-paths where it is not assigned, it is never used. The code could be fixed just as easily (and potentially more correctly) by putting "else { continue; }" on the first "if".

Comment: Thanks - worked perfectly and I've learnt something for the future!

Comment: @Iridium I think that simply assigning a value in the declaration is clearer and simpler than adding "else { continue; }" sentence

Comment: @jorgehmv Based on the code we've been given, a null TYPE results in none of the following "if" statements being executed. Assuming this is the whole code for the row-processing loop, it seems to me that by putting "else { continue; }" it's making it much clearer that no further processing occurs on this row, otherwise it's necessary to read all of the following code to determine this.

Comment: @Iridium - You are 100% correct.  Which is the reason I have to downvote this answer.  It also has to do with the fact the user didn't explain the reason you have to assign a value.  As you point out, you don't actually have to, considering a string variable already has a default value.

Comment: The answer works, it solved the problem, it does not matter that string has null as default value (everything has a default value in c#). I do not agree with the downvote

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that you are not assign `strType` variable to *any* value *before* you use it.  According to C# compiler rules you **must** assign variable to **any** value before you begin to use it in any way.

In other words, what *should* be enough is assign an empty string before consditions, like shit for example:

```
strType = srting.Empty; //at least one value is already assigned!

while (rsData.Read())
{
    .... //your code here
}
```

Why this? To avoid ambiguity and not clear code presentation.

More on this, dierctly read a small article from Eric Lippert: [Why are local variables definitely assigned in unreachable statements?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/03/05/why-are-local-variables-definitely-assigned-in-unreachable-statements.aspx)

Comment: The potential side-effect with the code you provided is that if the dataset contains rows with null TYPEs interspersed with non-null ones, the value of TYPE from the previous non-null row will be used whenever a row with a null TYPE is encountered (providing there has been at least one row with non-null TYPE processed so far), which may or may not be desired.

Comment: @Iridium: I understand your point, but I didn't dig into the code flow, but express a concept. The correct **default** value has to be chose by OP itself. If you note, while loop is not complete in code provided, so...

Answer (score 0):

You should assign some value to local variable before you use it. You can initialize it in place where you declare it (before while block):

```
var strType = ""; // or null
```

Or (if you don't want strType to remember its value from previous iteration), make sure it gets initial value both when reader contains data, or when there is DbNull

```
strType = rsData["TYPE"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : rsData["TYPE"].ToString().Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

It complains because at the time of If statment the variable has not got any value.

just do `string strType = "";`

Answer (score 0):

This error means you didn't previously declare that variable. Just initialise those variables in the beginning of your while loop.

Example:

```
while (rsData.Read())
{
    string strType = string.Empty;
    string strwho = string.Empty; // Do this if you have the same error for strwho
    string strmetades = string.Empty; // Do this if you have the same error for strmetades

    // Your other code comes here
}
```

If you order your IF statements a little different, you can even avoid the reassigning of an empty value to the variable.

Answer (score -1):

be nice, use String.Empty;

```
string strType=String.Empty;
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the reason for his error, so the answer is sort of useless, the default value of a string is already an empty string.