# use of unassigned local variable when using a foreach Loop

Tags: c#, unassigned-variable

I have a code block that gets some data from a stored procedure. After I receive the data, I want to assign the value to "isExisting" depending on conditions. I don't want to assign a value to "isExisting" at the time of declaration.

```
bool isExisting;
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("some_stored_procedure", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("input", value));
        using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                    isExisting = false;
                else
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        if (row["Key"].ToString() == ValueToCompareWith)
                        {
                            isExisting = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                            isExisting = false;
                    }
                }

            }
            else
                isExisting = false;
        }
    }
}
if (!isExisting) //Step :getting error "use of unassigned local variable"
{
}
```

I think I have covered every condition and the variable "isExisting" will have a value when it reaches "Step", but still I get compiler error.

The Problem started becuase my code review tool is throwing a comment

"A dead store happens when a local variable is assigned a value that is not read by any subsequent instruction. Calculating or retrieving a value only to then overwrite it or throw it away, could indicate a serious error in the code. Even if it's not an error, it is at best a waste of resources. Therefore all calculated values should be used."
Noncompliant Code Example

```
void CalculateRate(int a, int b)
{
  int i;

  i = a + b; // Noncompliant; calculation result not used before value is overwritten
  i = DoSomething();  // Noncompliant; retrieved value not used
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    //  ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the compiler is not smart enough to know whether you're actually assigning a value to the variable.

You can resolve this ambiguity, and clean up your code a lot, by using some Linq:

```
bool isExisting;
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("some_stored_procedure", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("input", value));
        using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            isExisting = ds.Tables
                .OfType<DataTable>()
                .Take(1)
                .SelectMany(t => t.Rows.OfType<DataRow>())
                .Any(r => r["Key"].ToString() == ValueToCompareWith);
        }
    }
}
if (!isExisting)
{
}
```

---

Another approach would be to factor out the `isExisting` check to a separate method:

```
bool CheckIsExisting(object value, string valueToCompareWith) 
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("some_stored_procedure", conn))
       {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("input", value));
            using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                if (ds.Tables.Count != 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        if (row["Key"].ToString() == ValueToCompareWith)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
               }
           }
       }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then do:

```
if (!CheckIsExisting(value, ValueToCompareWith))
{
    // do something...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is a simpleton. It doesn't check all the logic to make sure that the variable always gets a value. That isn't it's job. Just give `isExisting` a default value to keep the compiler happy and your real code will set the correct value anyway (as you have already stated).

Comment: My code review tool says that I should not declare and assign the value, and the compiler is not able to figure out that at runtime, the value will be there. So, I am left stranded.

Comment: Are you sure that is what your code review tool says? It's pretty much the opposite of best practice...

Comment: Agree with @John3136. best practice is to set default value for any variable you create in the program.

Comment: I have added the code review comments in the question section. Kindly have a look @John3136

Comment: @RajatMalik That is true if it is a calculation etc (which yours isn't). It could also be because your code is not finished. You do actually read `isExisting` later, but perhaps it is optimised out because in your snippet you have an empty block. In this case I suggest understand what the tool is telling you, check scope (is it all the same `isExisting`?) and then ignore the error.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler can't know for sure if every piece of code will get hit - for example, if there could be no rows in this loop:

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
```

so therefore that entire if block won't be hit.

Set a default.

Comment: I have done a count of rows, so I have covered by bases. The point is compiler is not able to understand that I have covered all possible cases.

Comment: Why the fundamental problem with setting the default value? In memory, technically the default(bool) is false. So initializing it as as false is better. If you REALLY need a "neither true nor false", use a Nullable<bool> or shorthand "bool?" and default it to null.

Answer (score 0):

**Default value** of **`Bool`** is **`false`** .Provide it at your code .

```
bool isExisting=false;
```

Your entire Business logic written in the code should take care for

```
if (!isExisting) {
}
```

Main logic behind is Compiler hardly bother what you scripted .It Only want the assigned value before making it use in any condition.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449635/use-of-unassigned-local-variable-if-statements) to understand more .